# What's the difference between HttpContext.Handler and HttpContext.CurrentHandler?

Tags: asp.net

I can't understand what is the difference between HttpContext.Handler and HttpContext.CurrentHandler.

Anyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MSDN:

The currently executing handler that is referenced by the CurrentHandler property might be different than the handler that is referenced by the Handler property. This can occur when another handler was requested by using the Execute method or the Transfer method. When the currently executing handler finishes processing, the previously determined handler is restored.